# How to fix this broken Gnome Shell ?

Tags: gnome, themes, icons

Any idea how I can fix this theme? The gap between the icons are bigger than usual and the dock is mis-positioned to a lower portion of the screen!

Comment: Screenshot would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the theme was poorly built. You can always edit the theme elements and make them right according to gnome icons guidelines, but if you are not that patient then find some other theme and apply it.
If you want to edit the then the icon themes are in
`/usr/share/icons/*your theme name*`